# how can i force a rerender of the map in azuremaps?

Tags: javascript, azure-maps

I'm trying to make a search function for my indoor azuremaps project, I can search throught the loaded geojson shapes based on name. Now when I highlight, or click on a search result I want it to show the corresponding room in a different color, to do this I made a switch case statement in the data driven styling of the layer, but when I change the corresponding property nothing happens. I assume I have to rerender the map.

```js
//Add a layer for rendering the outline of polygons.
        var polygonExtrusionLayer = new atlas.layer.PolygonExtrusionLayer(datasource, null, {
            height: ['*', ['+', 1, ['to-number', ['get', 'Bouwlaag']]], floorheight],
            base: ['*', ['to-number', ['get', 'Bouwlaag']], floorheight],
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            fillColor: ['case',
                ['<', ['to-number', ['get', 'Bouwlaag']], currentFloor],
                'lightblue',
                ['case',
                    ['==', ['get', 'resultId'], resultId],
                    'red',
                    'blue'
                ]
            ],
            filter:
                ['all',
                    ['any',
                        ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'Polygon'],       //Only render Polygon or MultiPolygon in this layer.
                        ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'MultiPolygon']
                    ],
                    ['<=', ['to-number', ['get', 'Bouwlaag']], currentFloor]
                ]
        });
```

```js
function featureClicked(id) {
    var shape = datasource.getShapeById(id);
    console.log(id)
    resultId = id;
    currentFloor = Number(shape.getProperties().Bouwlaag);
    shape.addProperty('resultId', id);
}
```

I searched online and in this article([text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/web-sdk-best-practices) it says that the map canvas is refreshed when I call the addProperty feature of a shape, but when I do so nothing happens. I have a similar question when updating the floor I'm looking at, nothing changes, do I have to keep creating and removing layers, or am I missing something that will allow me to for a refresh/rerender of the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Azure Maps Creator Indoor maps platform, the data source is in vector tile form and can't be edited in the client, thus `shape.addProperty` won't do anything.

Looking at your code, you could use the shapes ID instead of a `resultId` in your layer, then update the layer settings using `layer.setOptions`. For example:

```js
function featureClicked(id) {
    polygonExtrusionLayer .setOptions({
     fillColor: ['case',
                ['<', ['to-number', ['get', 'Bouwlaag']], currentFloor],
                'lightblue',
                ['case',
                    ['==', ['ID'], id],
                    'red',
                    'blue'
                ]
            ]
    });
}
```

Note that you will need to make sure that the layer and the `currentFloor` value is available in that function.

Comment: thanks, a lot, I didn't think of using setOptions, now it works the way I want